# Why did Senator mention "dorsal fin" ?

Tags: timecop

At the beginning of the time travel movie Timecop (1994), George warns Senators about the time travel. He decides to police this technology. So Senator McComb comes forward to chair the mission. Then another Senator says to George:

> Ah. Young Senator McComb. Why not? You'll like him, George. He's very
>   much like you, except his **dorsal fin**'s a bit bigger.

Why did Senator mention "dorsal fin" ? 
Dorsal fin is the part which belongs to an aquatic animals.

Comment: Small fish/sharks shouldn't mess with the larger fish/sharks- they'll just end up eaten?

Comment: Possibly meaning **like you, he is a predator but a bigger one**

Comment: In this case the "dorsal fin" is not referring to any aquatic animal, it's specifically referring to the dorsal fins of **sharks**.

Comment: sharks also belongs to an aquatic animals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a reference to McComb's *ambition*. Senator Uttley clearly thinks that the agency guy (Spota) is full of shit and that this is all an elaborate shakedown for money to police a technology that he doesn't really believe works, akin to the financial fiasco that was the ["Star Wars" Strategic Defense Initiative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_Defense_Initiative). He uses the word [*shark*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shark#shark_Noun_200) in the unpalatable sense of the word (e.g that this is basically a hustle of some sort).

> *"Who wants to subchair the oversight on this sucker?"*
>
> *Trick question. If this was some kind of science fiction fairy story, being involved with it could be major ammunition for an opponent come next reelection campaign: Ladies and gentlemen, the incumbent senator believes in time travel. I wonder, does he also believe in Santa Claus, the Tooth Fairy and the Easter Bunny? Little bitty green men from Mars...?
>
>   Jesus, it would be worse than getting caught in bed with a trio of hookers. But if it was real...*
>
> <sub><sup>[Timecop: A Novel](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Timecop.html?id=rRUUJ4dLy48C&redir_esc=y)</sup></sub>

He identifies that Senator McComb is an even bigger 'shark' than Spota, not only a hustler but also a *[predator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_predator)*, and hence worthy of his immediate respect.